# SaxParser replacing text while downloading?

Tags: java, saxparser

I have a Java SAXparser that downloads and parses, using parse(new InputSource(conn.getInputStream())). Unfortunately, sometimes it gives error when downloading a site's xml: "XML or text declaration not at start of entity"
Apparently this is bad xml, declaration has to be first:

```
<!DOCTYPE ... stuff here ...>
<?xml  ... stuff here ...?>
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to ignore this error. I suppose I could download the entire xml, then use regex or something to fix this, then parse it, but it seems this wouldn't have the benefit of parsing as it's downloading? Is there a way to replace it while it's parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy solution**: read the first line from the stream, consuming those bytes, and then pass it to the parser.

**Proper Java solution**: create an intermediate stream interface that wraps any kind of stream and offers a SAX parser compatible stream in return. Then create a class implementing that interface specifically for your case.

That way, you can detect the problematic header before it ever reaches the SAX parser.

**Edit**: I would just use the Apache commons XML parser, or a DOM parser instead of SAX. Also, unless your XML is **really** long, there's not much difference in parsing it during or after the download.

Comment: How would I make an intermediate stream? What Java class does this?

Comment: It seems DOM would be slower (http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/10927_3824221_2/Android-XML-Parser-Performance.htm), and it already takes around 100-600ms to parse the file (generally < 50kb).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). It can deal with wrongly formatted xml.